# VBA code for filling data in the file without ID?

Tags: html, vba

I tried to fill in data to the website fields,
i am able to fill in first 4 but the fifth one doesn't work, 
i tried to getelementsbyName, ClassName, but still doesn't work, 
can anyone help?
here is the code i used:

```
With ie.document
    .all.Item("first_name").Value = "FirstName"
    .all.Item("last_name").Value = "Lastname"
   .all.Item("email_address").Value = "Email@email.com"
    .all.Item("phone").Value = "201-222-1111"
    .all.Item("dba_name").Value = "business name"
End With
```

here is the HTML.

```html
<div class="formbox">
    <div class="padding">
      <div class="inside">
          <div id="formfield">
      <!--<p>Click Here For Help
      <img src="/images/helpbutton.jpg">
      </p> -->

    <input type="hidden" name="username" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="password" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="isTsys" value="" /> 

    <span id = "partner_name" style = "display:none">HAPPY TEAM</span>



        <div style="position:relative;width:600px;margin-left:2em;">
        <div style="margin-bottom:1em;width:90%;font-size:14px;border-bottom:1px solid #d3dde3;color:#3d7499;font-weight:bold;">Partner Name</div>
        <p>HAPPY TEAM</p>
    <div style="margin-bottom:1em;width:90%;font-size:14px;border-bottom:1px solid #d3dde3;color:#3d7499;font-weight:bold;">Contact</div>
        <p>
        <label>* First Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="first_name" value="" class="form_input"  />
        </p>
        <p><label>* Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="last_name" value="" class="form_input"  />
      </span>
        </p>
        <p><label>Email Address</label>
        <input type="text" name="email_address" value="" class="form_input field_input"  />
        </p>
         <p><label>* Phone</label>
         <input type="text" name="phone" value="" class="form_input" maxlength="15" 0="" 1="onKeyUp="autotab(this,'dba_name')""  />        </p>
        <div style="margin-bottom:1em;width:90%;font-size:14px;border-bottom:1px solid #d3dde3;color:#3d7499;font-weight:bold;">Company</div>
         <p><label><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="popup" name="dba_name" tabindex="-1">* DBA Name/Trading Name</a></label>
        <input type="text" name="dba_name" value="" class="form_input field_input"  />        </p>
           <p><label>Address</label>
        <input type="text" name="dba_address" value="" class="form_input field_input"  />        </p>

        <p><label>City</label>
        <input type="text" name="dba_city" value="" class="form_input field_input"  />        </p>
        <p><label>State/Province</label>
          <input style="margin-top: .3em; border: 2px solid #70AAD1; font-size: 15px; padding: 4px 10px;" class="state_province" name="dba_state" id="state">

        </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
.querySelector("a[name=dba_name]").Value = "business name"
```

So

```
With ie.document

 .querySelector("a[name=dba_name]").Value = "business name"
```

Failing that potentially,

```
 .querySelector("a[name=dba_name]").innerText = "business name"
```

---

The following, `a[name=dba_name]`, is a CSS selector. It targets an element by its styling. This selector targets elements with `a` tags having attribute `name` with value `dba_name`. As I am applying the selector with `querySelector` method, only the first match will be retrieved.

Comment: it doesn't work either,it returned Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method.

Comment: What version of IE are you running?

Comment: IE version 11, more accurately is Version: 11.112.17134.0

Comment: If you do F12 in IE and look in the emulation tab; what is the document mode?